# Причастный оборот в придаточной части предложения. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, причастия

Добрый день. Нужно ли ставить запятую между союзом и началом причастного оборота, находящегося в придаточной части сложно-подчиненного предложения? Вот предложение:

*Он долго слонялся по пустыне, когда уставший и потерявший последнюю надежду, нашел колодец.*

Нужна ли запятая после союза *когда*?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение составлено недостаточно корректно, союз КОГДА здесь желательно заменить союзом ПОКА НЕ: "Он долго слонялся по пустыне, пока, уставший и потерявший последнюю надежду,  не нашел колодец".

Это СПП с придаточным времени. Союз ПОКА НЕ используется в предложениях со значением предшествования, сравнить: "С минуту он остался неподвижен, пока не убедился, что дал промах".

В главном предложении подразумевается подлежащее "он", к которому относится обособленный определительный оборот.